# Counting the number of times a user try to guess a number in (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm running a guessing game of numbers ranging from 1-5.
And I want to display the number of failed trials a user tries to guess in PHP.

I tried $_SESSION. It worked actually but keeps on counting even if I refresh the page.

Is there any other ways? Help a brother, please.

I'm a beginner.

Comment: That is an expected behavior. Refreshing the page doesn't clear the session.

Comment: if you want to restore the counter after  refresh  page you don't need to put it in session just put it as  variable

Comment: Incrementing the number of tries must be connected to the FORM submit, reloading (GET request) should not increment it.